# Permission To Access Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I inherited an `asp.net` application that gives users access to pages based off the value in a `SQL Server` database field.  As each page is loaded a procedure is run to check the user id and the page name against the database to determine if the user id has access to the specific page.  If `access = 'Yes'` the user is allowed to view all elements on the page, if `access = 'No'` the user is logged out of the system and re-directed to the log-on screen.

What would I need to do in order to store ALL pages that the user id has access to in the beginning so once the user is logged in they only see what they have access to, as opposed to a check being performed each time a user requests access to a page?

Comment: I only have a few levels of permissions and a few pages to track so I push them into the session variable. Having said that, checking for a single user against a database is not that costly time wise.

Comment: @Bindrid - the application has roughly 80 pages, and hitting the database and waiting for a response is my lagtime as this server is also hit for multiple other procedures.

Comment: You can add those pages with names in tables when user is created at the first time.

Comment: @Hemal - the userid is linked to a table that houses all pages and if the user has access to it on the userid field.  So if I am understanding you, I already have this set-up.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: @Hemal - the problem is a call is made to the db each time a user requests a page.  I would like to remove that process and on logon have ALL pages the user has access to stored in either a List<string> somehow instead of a database call each time a page is requested.

Comment: Is it suitable, if you store all pages as a comma seperated string in a session variable, and when user logs in, you just check for page name index in that session variable?If I am not wrong....

Comment: @Hemal - yes it sounds like that is a viable solution as I would only need to parse the session variable to see if user has access.  Can you show example of how to set this up/?

Comment: I will show some code in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98954/discussion-between-hemal-and-fartstopper).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show some code.
Its something like this.

```
string session_string="";
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING);
cn.open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection=cn;
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText="select name_of_pages from permission where username='YOUR_USERNAME'";
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(rdr.hasRows==true){
    while(rdr.Read()){
        session_string=rdr["name_of_pages"] + ",";//You need to declare this variable globally before
        session_string=session_string + rdr["name_of_pages"] + ","; //USE THIS LINE , NOT PREVIOUS ONE
    }
}
rdr.close();//DONT FORGET THIS ALSO
cn.close();//DONT FORGET THIS
    Session["pages"]=session_string;
    //Now to check
    if(Session["pages"].Contains("Index.aspx")){
        //PERFORM SOMETHING POSITIVE

    }
    else
    {
        //PERFORM SOMETHING NEGATIVE
    }
```

Change some code according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we use FormsAuthenticationTicket  once the user has logged on.  With the ticket, we go against the database and get the users rolls and persmissons.  This goes into a session variable. (since you are using asp.net)  We then check the users page request against that object in the session in Global asa.  If they failed, we send them to the loggin page.

Comment: Can this hold multiple values, or can it only hold one value?  Examples I have seen only show it storing 1 value.

Comment: you can have as many roles as you want.  I can't imagine that there is a separate permission for all 80 pages , they have to be broken into some sections and each section would be given a role.  The you can let the framework handle , by caching , which roles the user has permission for

Comment: @ScottSelby - for the most part their are about 5 groups who have the same permissions to the same pages.  However, there are a few instances where an individual user needs access to 1 page that is not in the default 'pages' for the group they are contained in.  How should those instances be handled?

Comment: same situation so the object we shove into the session contains both.  We first check group permissions since that takes care of 90 percent of the cases. If that fails then we check for individual pages. If that fails then they are sent off

Comment: yea @FartStopper - "How should those instances be handled"  That question kind of implies that you should be reaching out to some one that is more senior ad has a bit more knowledge about programming in general and have a conversation about that .  Your solution is going to be pretty specific to your needs.  If there is no one senior to you on your project you way want to contract someone for a minimal amount of time to have conversations about basic architecture of the app , stuff like that can't really be answered properly on here